# Is it possible setting conditional css based on hierarchy elements?

Tags: css

Consider the following HTML:

```
<div>
   <p>
     <strong>Title</strong>
   </p>
   <p>
     some resular text....
   </p>
</div>
```

I want to add padding to paragraph only if it has 'strong' inside it.

Is it possible using CSS only (no JS)?

Comment: In your example couldn't you just add padding to the strong tag and it would produce the same result?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a CSS parent selector?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you would do this:

```
p > strong {
    padding:10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. Refer [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11529495/importance-of-css-stylesheet-hierarchy) for learning the rules.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/n05jaua4/3/

HTML:

```
<div>
   <p>
     <strong>Title inside paragraph</strong>
   </p>
   <p>
     some resular text....
   </p>
</div>
<strong>Title</strong>
```

CSS:

```
p strong{
   padding-top: 50px;
    padding-right: 30px;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
    padding-left: 80px;
}
```